# AWS API Gateway & Lambda – No conversion from text to application/json

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I created a Lambda function and added an API Gateway trigger. Adding the trigger created an API as a "Lambda Proxy" and "proxy resource". This is good because per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-proxy-resource?icmpid=docs_apigateway_console) a proxy resource "transforms the output from the Lambda function to HTTP responses." However, it returns `200` but calls the error function of my ajax request. Debugging the error, I see `parsererror` and `No conversion from text to application/json`. Is there something I'm missing in API Gateway? I tried adding `application/json => Empty` to the "Method Response" but no-go.

Here's what my Lambda function returns:

```
return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "Email added to system."
}
```

Here's the AJAX:

```
  var formData = $("#submitEmail").serializeArray();
  console.log(formData);

  $.ajax({
      url : "https://<REDACTED>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/SubmitEmail",
      type: "POST",
      data : formData,
      dataType: "application/json",
      success: function(data, textStatus, xhr)
      {
          console.log("SUCCESS")
          console.log(xhr.status)
      },
      error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
      {
          console.log("ERROR")
          console.log(xhr.status)
          console.log(textStatus)
          console.log(errorThrown)
      }
  });
```

Comment: Not sure it will solve it, but can you try to set the body to `"body": { msg: "Email added to system." }`? It would make more sense to send an object rather than a string if the content type is `application/json`.

Comment: Yeah, `JSON.parse("Email added to system.")` throws an error. You need to actually provide valid JSON.

Comment: Hmm, that breaks the function and gives me a 502. If you look at the very bottom of [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-output-format), `body` expects a string.

Comment: @sambol you need to do `"body": JSON.stringify({ msg: "Email added to system." })`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how to explain this, but I was able to get it to call the success function of my AJAX request. I think it was mismatch of data types. Here's what I changed.

Modified my ajax request:

```
  var formData = {
    email: $("#email").val()
  }

  dataType: "json"  (instead of "application/json")
```

Lambda function:

```
return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    "body": json.dumps({
        "msg": "Email added to system."
    })
}
```

For API Gateway, I have nothing listed under "Response Headers for 200" and "Response Body for 200".